# jQuery/AJAX post() - a few problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, pdo

I'm basically working on a site in which a user repeatedly clicks a button, increasing his score each time he clicks. I don't want the page to refresh between each click, so I'm using AJAX.

The problems I'm having currently are as follows:

1. When I try to set my javascript `var` to `=` `<? echo $result['count']; ?>`, it doesn't seem to work.
2. I don't understand how to correctly use PDO to `UPDATE` a MySQL table with a calculation in the query, such as `$update = $dbh->execute("UPDATE count SET count='$count'+1 WHERE username='$username'");`. Is this the correct syntax for the calculation and is this the right way to do it in PDO?

Here is the code for my testing page which I am using for the clicking system:

```
<html>
<?php 

$hostname = 'localhost';
$username2 = 'refrigerator';
$password = 'xxx';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=refrigerator", $username2, $password);
$username = $_COOKIE["user"];

$rows = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count FROM count WHERE username = '$username'");
            $rows->execute();   
            $result = $rows->fetchALL();
            $result['count'] = $count;  

if(isset($_POST['action'])){    

    if ($_POST['action'] == 'increase'){

        $update = $dbh->execute("UPDATE count SET count='$count'+1 WHERE username='$username'");            
    }
}
?>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    var count = <? echo $result['count']; ?>;

        $("#update").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "button.php",
            data: {"action":"increase"},
            success: function(update) {

                count++;
                $("#counter").html(+count);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<button id="update" type="button">Button</button>
<div id="counter"><? echo $result['count']; ?></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot, any help would be greatly appreciated. Even if you can point me in the right direction which will help me answer my questions, that would be awesome.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct tag settings on? you might not be able to use `<? ... ?>` and may need to use `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: @Dutchie432
Thanks for the reply
I'm pretty sure I need to use the short tags, because when I use the full ones then I get an error saying that the variable $result isn't defined or something.

Comment: after the line `$result['count'] = $count;`, if you put `die($result['count'])` - do you see the expected result?

Comment: @Dutchie432 
Thanks again, that doesn't return anything at all so it must be a problem with the PDO. I do get a notice that there is an undefined variable 'count' on line 14 (`$result['count'] = $count;`) which I don't really understand because I'm defining that variable in that line...

any ideas? 

thanks

Comment: You need to check again. You are never defining `$count`

Comment: @Dutchie432 really?! But I said $result['count'] = $count...
does it need to be $count = $result['count']?
thanks

Comment: Oh not it says undefined index 'count', not variable. Does that mean the 'count' inside the [square brackets] is wrong? because I'm certain that count is one of the fields in the table that it's referring to :(

Comment: The term Index implies a position in an array, and an array is defined by `[]`. That being said, whenever you get an undefined index, it's going to be something in the square brackets `[]`. I would look into your SQL statement to make sure it's correct. `SELECT count FROM count` sounds a little weird to me. Is your table/view actually named `count`?

Answer (score 0):

You should have:

```
$count = $result['count'];
```

Instead of:

```
$result['count'] = $count;
```

The variable to the left of the = sign is what is receiving the assignment from whatever value is on the right of the = sign.

In your update statement you could, instead of using your count variable, could do:

```
 $update = $dbh->execute("UPDATE count SET count=count+1 WHERE username='$username'");
```